# Finding a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis of subspace $ U_1 +U_2 $ of a vector space $V$. $ U_1, U_2 \subseteq V$:
$V = \mathbb R[t]$, $U_1 = \{ f \mid t^2-4t+3 \text{ divides } f \}, U_2 = \{g \mid t^2-5t+4 \text{ divides } g\}. $

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{B}=\{ t^i(t-1) \; \big|\; i\ge 0\}$. Note that $\mathcal{B}$ is clearly independent. Let $f=t^2-4t+3$ and $g=t^2-5t+4$. Now $f-g=t-1$. Then $t^if-t^ig=t^i(t-1)\in U_1+U_2$ for all $i\ge 0$. Thus $\text{span}\ \mathcal{B}\subseteq U_1+U_2$. Now let $f'f+g'g\in U_1+U_2$ for some $f',g'\in \mathbb{R}[t]$. Since $t-1$ divides $f'f+g'g$, we have that $f'f+g'g \in \text{span}\ \mathcal{B}$. Thus $U_1+U_2=\text{span}\ \mathcal{B}$, giving us that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $U_1+U_2$.